# How can uncertainty bars be specified for a Seaborn barplot?

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

A Seaborn barplot can be created in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(
         [
             ['variable_a', 0.656536, 0.054560],
             ['variable_b', 0.425124, 0.056104],
             ['variable_c', 0.391201, 0.049393],
             ['variable_d', 0.331990, 0.032777],
             ['variable_e', 0.309588, 0.027449],
         ],
         columns = [
             'index',
             'mean',
             'statistical_uncertainty'
         ]
    )
df.index = df['index']
del df['index']
df

p = sns.barplot(df["mean"], df.index);
plt.show;
```

How can the uncertainty bars be added to the barplot? This appears to be a promising approach, but I'm not sure how to proceed: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw the error bar using `plt.errorbar` on top of the plot:

```
p = sns.barplot(df["mean"], df.index)

# to enhance visibility of error bars, 
# you can draw them twice with different widths and colors:
p.errorbar(y=range(len(df)), 
           x=df['mean'], 
           xerr=df.statistical_uncertainty, 
           fmt='none',
           linewidth=3, c='w')

p.errorbar(y=range(len(df)), 
           x=df['mean'], 
           xerr=df.statistical_uncertainty, 
           fmt='none',
           c='r')
plt.show;
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help. Nice touch with adding the border too.